# were anchored from?

Tags: meaning-in-context, figurative-language

I'm translating an English article to Persian (my mother tongue). I didn't understand the meaning of this phrase or anything!:

"The employee relations aspect of sustainable HRM reflects an organization’s concern for employee well-being and its motivation to attract and develop the HR base of the organization.
Response options for all multi-item measures in this study ***were anchored from*** (1) strongly disagree to (5) strongly agree."

what do the highlighted words mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the response options in the study **were ranging from** "strongly disagree" on one end, to "strongly agree" on the other hand.

Therefore "were anchored from" means "were ranging from" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

A literal anchor provides an attachment point for something.  A ship's anchor attaches to the bottom of a body of water, and allows the ship to move a limited distance away from that point.  Some objects have more than one "anchor".

The original post's context is a survey.  The survey-taker asked the person being surveyed to answer the questions on a scale from 1 through 5.  To provide meanings for the numbers, the survey-taker probably asked something like, "Please answer these questions on a scale from 1 through 5, where 1 is 'strongly disagree' and 5 is 'strongly agree'."

Figuratively, the numbers 1 and 5 are attached to these meanings.  The survey responses can vary within this limited range.  In the example article, the author uses the word "anchor" figuratively to indicate that the meanings of 1 and 5 were defined this way, and the meanings of the other numbers were probably interpolated by the person being surveyed.

Answer (score 0):

That's the first time I've encountered the phrase "anchored from" to refer to the range of answers on a questionnaire. When language is "abused" like that in a certain domain, people outside the domain often apply the **-ese** suffix to the writing, as a way of characterizing it as being full of jargon.  That writing is definitely  "HRM-ese".